# External style sheets effect on webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I load the data of any webpage and this web page style sheets affect on my web page.
**Mywebpage**

```
<html>
 <head>
 <script>
 $('#mydiv').load('externalData.php');
 </script>
  </head>
<body>
<div id="mydiv" >
<h1>Here is some content</h1>
</div>
<div id="otherdiv">
//other div
</div>
<button>click</button>
</body>
 </html>
```

**externalData.php**

```
 <?php

echo file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');

 ?>
```

How can I avoid that these are not affect on my div 'otherdiv'.

Comment: put  your css in the footer of your page after the page is loaded

Comment: Use an iframe to isolate external content.

Comment: dont steal other peoples web sites. problem solved

Comment: I am using jquery to load the data. so, jquery is run when the document is fully loaded. Therefor, put css in footer is useless.

Comment: I did not want to use iframe due to some reason.

Comment: use cUrl + [strip_tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php). passing in allowable DOM elements as the 2nd argument, such as `p, a, br, div, blockquote, etc`, basically everything other than `head`, `script`, `style`, `link`.

Comment: I think it's a bad overall architecture to proxy a website through PHP+file_get_contents+URL+JQuery. It's bad for reasons of performance, security and because it breaks common design principles like MVC. I think this is the reason, why so many users upvoted the comment "dont steal other peoples web sites" above. There is a truth behind that sentence...

Comment: look into "scoped" style tags

Comment: Whether or not it is bad architecture, that doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, with CSS, style sheets are cascading. So simply put a different stylesheet after your call to file_get_contents, which says how the div is actually supposed to look. The second style sheet will be favoured over the one from file_get_contents.